# Replace comma with OR conditional (PHP)

Tags: php

I have an option for the users to write which pages they don't want to see.

Simplifying, is a text input where they will write the pages names, such "contact", "bio" etc.

While they tip "contact, bio" I have to create a conditional to hide these pages, so the content would be displayed like this on the code:

```
if (('contact') || ('bio')) {
    hide content
}
```

Typing just one page would be easy but with more pages, I don't know how to replace the comma to the OR conditional. How can I do it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason they need to type this? Why not give them checkboxes on what to hide?

Comment: Your process is confusing and fragile

Comment: Your `if` statement condition there will always be true, by the way. And you probably want to do something like use [`explode()`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then check to see if what you're looking for is in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first take user's input in one variable 
Lets say you got it in `$string`

```
$string = "contact,bio,home";
$token = strtok($string, ",");
$i=0;  // To know how manny keywords are there.
while ($token != false)
{
echo "$token<br>";
$user_ip[i++] = strtok(",");
}
```

and then you need to parse all pages name by , and store it in array.
lets say you stored it in `$user_ip`

Then you need to compare it like

```
if ( ($user_ip[0] === "contact") || ($user_ip[0] === "bio") {
}
```

and check above if for all members of `$user_ip.`

Comment: the answer is getting closer to what I want. The thing is that I don't know which pages they'll want to exclude. I'm new to PHP so if you could explain how to parse the pages name, would be great.

Comment: The second part is confusing me. Since I don't know which data they typed and how many, how to compare?

Comment: For one question one answer. For other question you should ask new question.  When someone answers your question you should upvote or accept its answer. this is how stackoverflow work.

Comment: The question is the same, I just want to understand how it works. Anyway I marked your answer as the right one. If you kind, could you explain how to compare?

Comment: how much data is given is same as variable "i" so you need to do check for $user_ip[0] to $user_ip[i-1]. And for comparasion i have answered statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code:

```
$skip_pages = explode(",","contact, bio");
$current_page = "contact";

if(in_array($current_page,$skip_pages)){
    //redirect page to ....
}

//continue with page
```